# Is there a simple way to create custom types in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Just want to make a simple custom type from `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` to, say, just shorter`[arrayList]` or something like that and put it into a module for convenience. Looked into `Add-Type` but couldn't figure out if it fits and how to do it exactly. What I want to get is:

```
[ArrayList]<-[System.Collections.ArrayList] #Something like that
$myArList=New-Object ArrayList
$myArList.Add(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a [type accelerator](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/09/simplify-your-script-by-creating-powershell-type-accelerators/).

```
[accelerators]::add('arrayList','System.Collections.ArrayList')
```

I would avoid using non-standard accelerators. PowerShell has good tab completion support for classes since at least v3.

So if you type `[arrayl`<kbd>TAB</kbd> then it will complete the full name for you.

[Ryan Bemrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821878/ryan-bemrose) brought up a great point; the `[accelerators]` type accelerator is not available by default, but you can create it like so:

```
$acc = [psobject].assembly.gettype("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$acc::Add('accelerators', $acc)
```

Comment: The `[accelerators]` accelerator isn't enabled by default on my PS, though I can add it with `$acc = [psobject].assembly.gettype("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators"); $acc::Add('accelerators', $acc)`

Answer (score 8):

If you simply want to avoid re-typing `System.Collections.ArrayList` all the time, you can simply assign a type literal to a variable and use that:

```
$ListType = [System.Collections.ArrayList]
$MyArrayList = New-Object $ListType
# more code
$AnotherArrayList = New-Object $ListType
```

or, using the v5.0 `new()` constructor:

```
$MyArrayList = $ListType::new()
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I like this one too.